# What is this de 地 or deyu 地与 doing in ...只有选好了工作地点，才能有选择地与招聘单位联系和洽谈...?

Tags: meaning

I can't see how this hangs together. What is '有选择地‘ doing here? This comes from a 听力专项训练。 The sentence is:

> 选择工作地点是应届毕业生找工作的一个重要步骤，因为只有选好了工作地点，才能有选择地与招聘单位联系和洽谈，才能迈出与用人单位联系的第一步。

In a similar vein I found:

我们不得不悲伤地与我们的客人们告别。 If I remove 与我们的客人们 it still seems to make sense.
我们不得不悲伤地告别。

But if I take: 才能有选择地与招聘单位联系和洽谈， and remove 与招聘单位

才能有选择地系和洽谈 then how should I interpret '有选择地' ??

What is the function of '有选择地' in my sentence?

Edit: Could it mean: 'optimally'? 'optimally relate and discuss'??

Comment: JSYK Oxford has 'selectively' in their dictionary as ADVERB 有选择地 && here's an example sentence I found in another dictionary 有选择地应用新的科技成果 
yǒu xuǎnzé de yìngyòng xīn de kējì chéngguǒ
make selective use of new scientific and technological achievements

Comment: "有选择地与招聘单位联系和洽谈" here sounds Westernised Chinese language (歐化中文) to me.  I guess it actually means "选择適當的招聘单位去联系和洽谈".

Answer (score 3):

> http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/characters/33/
>
> *[粵] dei6 | [國] de5*
>
> *[suffix] used after an adjective (usually polysyllabic) to form a literary adverbial phrase*

Example:

- 巧妙 (clever) | 巧妙地 (cleverly)
- 強烈 (strong) | 強烈地 (strongly)
- 準確 (accurate) | 準確地 (accurately)

有选择(selective) may not be a common adjective, but 有选择地 is still a literary adverbial phrase.

**有选择地** 与 招聘单位 **联系**

- 与(with) is preposition
- 招聘单位 (hiring department) is the object
- **有选择地**  is  the adverb modifies the verb **联系**

One more example:

- 無條件投降 "unconditional surrender"  is adjective + noun
- 無條件地投降 "unconditionally surrender" is adverb and verb

**Update:**

Seems like that dictionary might left something out.

有选择 is not an adjective,  it is a descriptive phrase, functions as an adjective only when it is a part of an adverbial phrase 有选择地.

Example:

Descriptive phrase:

- 漫不經心 ( not paying attention)
- 假仁假義 ( fake kindness)
- 貪得無厭 ( greed with no limit)

Adverbial phrase:

- 漫不經心地 ( absentmindedly )
- 假仁假義地 ( pretentiously )
- 貪得無厭地 ( greedily)

Comment: Thanks! "used after an adjective " Does that dictionary really consider ‘有选择‘ to be an adjective followed by 地? 百度有：http://www.ichacha.net/%E6%9C%89%E9%80%89%E6%8B%A9%E5%9C%B0.html There it is sometimes 'selectively' and sometimes 'optionally'. I think I prefer 'optionally' in my sentence.

Answer (score 1):

有选择地 = selectively

有选择地联系 = selectively get in touch with

选择工作地点是应届毕业生找工作的一个重要步骤，
Choosing a job location is an important step for a recently graduated student,

因为只有选好了工作地点，
because only when you have chosen the job location,

才能有选择地与招聘单位联系和洽谈，
can you selectively get in touch with (potential) employers and talk,

才能迈出与用人单位联系的第一步。
only then can you take the first steps towards contacting (potential) employers.

I break this down like this:

才能 [有选择地] [与招聘单位联系和洽谈]，
only then can [selectively] [with employers get in touch and talk]

basically, 2 adverbial phrases.

Obviously, whoever wrote this has never heard of the Internet or working from home. A computer programmer can do the job anywhere!